# Отправка данных (ajax) на сервер для обработки и получение результата [закрыт]

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Доброго времени суток. Под утро все сбилось в кучу, не могу правильно составить запрос и вернуть его в страницу. Прошу совета/помощи:

index.html

```
<form>  
  <input type="text" name="var_1" value="555" />
  <input type="text" name="var_2" value="777" />
  <input type="text" name="var_3" value="111" />
</form>

<script>
  var postparam = $('form').serializeArray();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: postparam,
    success: function(data)
    });
</script>
```

Как получить "name" и "value" в some.php, если я собираюсь по "name" делать выборку из БД?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В переменной *postparam* у вас будет массив формата *[{name:"var_1", value:"555"}, {name:"var_2", value:"777"}, {name:"var_3", value:"111"}]* На странице *some.php*, к прмеру через foreach, получаете все ваши данные.

Comment: foreach ($_GET['name'] as $value) echo '<script>alert("'.$value.'");</script>';  
Попытался так проверить, но страница лишь перезагружается, хотя в URL данные остаются.